# how to show google ads inside webview with html content

Tags: android, webview

I need [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvfaQ.png) type of requirement in the webview with ads,

```
String renderHtml = Helper.addDivIntoHtml(desc,FONT_COLOR, BG_COLOR, "12");           
            mWebViewNewsDetail.loadData(renderHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is website ad, you can not do it using mobile ads. For getting this kind of ads you have to apply for adsense account approval for website and when your website gets approved by google staff, you can integrate ads in your website.

Comment: Hello Jaydip
thanks for reply .

but other apps do the same. other app showing ads in the web view. we have two strring text and want to show ads in between these two string . after that show these merge content on the webview.

actual requirement as 
first paragraph
google ads
second(rest) paragraph
thanks in advance please provide some suggestion.